# What can I do if I need econometrics skills, but cannot get into econometrics courses?

Tags: phd, united-states, coursework

I am a first year Businesss major PhD student. I need to learn Econometrics, but my math is so bad that the professor does not allow me to attend the Statistics foundation course for Econometrics. I feel very bad because I cannot do research if I don’t take Econometrics courses, what worse is that other 2nd year courses are based on Econometrics. It means that I am very screwed that I am not able to do research methodology courses in my 1st year of PhD. Anything I can do?

Update: I am in a US-based university and the program is usually 5 years. I managed to enroll in an Econometrics course in another university, but as one may guess, I find it difficult without taking the prerequisite statistics course. Instead of struggling the whole semester, I decided to drop it two days ago. Now I feel a bit regretful, because that means I would not have chances to do Econometrics again due to the coursework plan.

It also means that I now need to study Math, Statistics, and Econometrics all by myself. I am owing a lot. What's the problem of me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you can surely do is take a math course improve your skills, so that you can then be accepted into the Statistics course.

Unfortunately, as the saying goes, there is no royal road.

Comment: This is the right path, and in the US it should be open. Talk to your advisor about getting the background you need.

Comment: Yes this does mean it may take you longer to finish your PhD.